# How to link google action with dialogflow using gaction CLI?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to automate the process of google action creation and deployment and for that I can find a a number of documents where gactions is being used to handle action console with action SDK.

I want to ask if their is any way i can link google action with my dialogflow agent using gaction CLI Or if any other CLI is already providing the support for same.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood an Actions on Google project will have a 'project id'. This is a Google Cloud Platform project, which gives your Action access to additional resources if you want, like Cloud Functions.

Dialogflow uses the same infrastructure, where the Dialogflow project id is a GCP project.

"gactions" as a command-line tool is not designed to work too closely with Dialogflow. However, as you know that your Action and Dialogflow share a common infrastructure, you could do some work yourself to use the [Dialogflow API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent) with your project ID to do some automation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Nick . I was trying to do something similar by extracting action json through gaction cli of an already integrated project(google action with dialogflow) where i could notice that it uses a fulfillment url to link to dialogflow which looks something like this "https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=#################" .If some where I could find this URL localtion in dialogflow console it could still serve my purpose.

Comment: It's probably somewhere in the developer documentation.